# confused about ElasticSearch memory consumption

Tags: elasticsearch

when I run localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v, I got the following stats:

```
heap.percent ram.percent ram.current ram.max   node
 71          79          199.5gb     252.1gb   es08-node1 
 57          84          211.5gb     252.1gb   es07-node0
```

I'm confused that I only gave each ES instance 30G memory, such as -Xmx30g -Xms30g, how come it consumed 199.5gb as showed above?

Comment: That's RAM, not heap. The 30GB are for heap.

Comment: And Lucene (each shard is a Lucene instance) is also using the file system cache (managed by the OS). And the file system cache is using RAM memory.

Comment: Have a read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/heap-sizing.html#_give_less_than_half_your_memory_to_lucene) about this.